# Condense large list of overlapping networks in CIDR format to greatest common denominator in Python

Tags: python, networking, ip-address

I have a text file that stores a large list of networks (250k+) that we use internally in the following format:

```
10.4.5.0/30
10.4.5.0/24
10.4.7.0/24
10.4.0.0/16
10.3.5.0/24
10.3.0.0/16
172.15.51.0/24
172.0.0.0/8
```

I'd like to try to reduce the list to make the processing more efficient. Using Python, how can I efficiently condense the list into the largest subnet that contains all the IPs? Are there any libraries that make this easier?

For example, the list above could be reduced to:

```
10.4.0.0/16
10.3.0.0/16
172.0.0.0/8
```

As an extension, is this possible in IPv6?

Comment: Have you tried with [IPy](https://github.com/autocracy/python-ipy)?

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this [github-IPy](https://github.com/autocracy/python-ipy)
Use `IPSet` to merge your IPs. It works well with ipv6. However I'm not quite sure about the performance. Maybe golang is better for such job.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified routing [trie](https://www.lewuathe.com/longest-prefix-match-with-trie-tree.html) would definitely do it, but I think that may be overkill when the following algorithm should work:

- turn all subnets into two integers: one for ip value `IP` and other for subnet length `Subnet`
- for each pair, compare it to your list of root pairs

```py
for s in subnets:
  markForRoots = False
  for r in roots:
    if ((s.IP ^ r.IP) >> s.Subnet) == 0: #if they share the same prefix
      if s.Subnet > r.Subnet: #if the current subnet is bigger
        # remove r from root
        markForRoots = True
  if markForRoots:
    # add s to roots
```